# How to clone() StringBuilder

Tags: java, memory, netbeans, arraylist, stringbuilder

Is there some ways how I could clone StringBuilder ? I am reading files by bits then convert these bits to ASCII chars after that I collect chars into String builder and when I have for example 8 chars I put that String Builder object into Array List. Then I clean it and again do the same. However I can't create new string builder because of memory and I can't do changes to that String builder because in Array List also that builder changes.

So I think I have to clone that String Builder and put it into Array List. There is just one problem String Builder don't have clone(). So what is my alternatives ?

Maybe someone could give some ideas what is neat way to do this considering about performance and memory.

ArrayList characters = new ArrayList(); 
    int counter = 0;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(blockSize-1);

while (mbb.hasRemaining()) {   

char charAscii = (char)mbb.get();


    counter++;
    charCounter++;

     if (counter == blockSize){

        sb.append(charAscii);
        characters.add(sb);//sb.toString()
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        counter = 0;

    }else{

        sb.append(charAscii);

     }

 if(!mbb.hasRemaining()){
    characters.add(sb);
}



}
fc.close();
return characters;
```

Comment: "i can't create new string builder because of memory" - a cloned StringBuilder will use a similar amount of memory, so how would this help you?

Comment: `new StringBuilder(oldbuilder.toString())` is the simplest way to copy a StringBuilder. You haven't actualy explained what you are trying to achieve, so you might be able to just store the String from the StringBuilder instead.

Comment: Yap understood that it won't help anyway.  So i am out of options becouse this characters.add(new StringBuilder(sb)); gives java outOffMemory exception

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you don't have the memory to create a new `StringBuilder`, then you don't have the memory to create a new `StringBuilder`, and cloning wouldn't change that.  The only real way to copy a `StringBuilder` is `new StringBuilder(myBuilder)`, or something equivalent.

If you're getting `OutOfMemoryException`, you'll need to either get more memory, or find some other way to reduce memory consumption.

Comment: It should be noted that this OutOfMemoryException doesn't mean the machine is out of memory, it means the JVM has hit its limit. It may be a machine limit or a JVM limit. I would recommend making sure you are telling Java to use enough memoryby passing in e.g. `-Xmx1024`

Answer (score 1):

You can clear `StringBuilder` object by:

1.

```
sb.delete(0, sb.length())
```

2.

```
sb = null;
sb = new StringBuilder();
```

For performance, 1. is the better option. But you cannot clone it anyway. For more info about clone see

- [Shallow copy and Deep Copy](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-clone-shallow-copy-and-deep-copy/#&slider1=1)
- [Clone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29)

Comment: In 2. `sb = null;` isn't necessary since `sb = new StringBuilder();` also overwrites `sb`. Also, I would think 1 may immediately impact memory consumption since it modifies the object, whereas 2 just changes what a variable points to, leaving any original object still in memory as a possibly candidate for garbage collection.

Comment: @LoganMay, I think 1) will make the previously allocated memory eligible for the garbage collection.

Comment: I agree that seems possible in theory. Is there any documentation you can point to that makes it explicitly clear whether the memory affected by the `delete` call is immediately freed or first has to be garbage collected?